# Can I express counting like this?

Tags: countability

If there are 2 but there aren't 4, is 'half 4' valid phrase to express 2? Otherwise, is it valid only when there are 4?

Comment: it is not clear what you are asking. Why would anyone express a number less clearly than by simply stating it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only case where a native speaker would say "half 4" would be talking about the time in British English, meaning "half an hour past four o'clock" (4:30).

You could say that two is "half *of* four," but this would never be used by a native speaker when counting.  They'd just say "two."  If you forgot the word "two," though, "half of four" would get your point across.

Answer (score 0):

It would be mathematically correct, but not common.

I have a joke clock with "numbers" written as √4 or 1221/111  but I'd never say "I have √4 children", except as a weird joke.  Similarly I'd never say "I have half of 4 children."